# Grass 7.2.1 error in Ubuntu 17.04 "failed to connect to session manager"

Tags: environment-variables, session

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop and `GRASS GIS`. While opening `GRASS GIS` I get this error:

```
Debug: failed to connect to session manager: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined?
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install GRASS GIS?

Comment: I just type sudo apt-get install grass.

Answer (score 2):

`SESSION_MANAGER` is an environment variable set up when you login via the GUI. `grass` is a GUI app. You cannot run `grass` from a <kbd>Ctrl F1</kbd> non-graphic terminal.

For examply ***my*** `SESSION_MANAGER` variable (on a GUI terminal) is:

```
SESSION_MANAGER=local/aardvark:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/9452,unix/aardvark:/tmp/.ICE-unix/9452
```

The number ("`9452`") is the `PID` of `/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary`, which owns the GUI session.